# Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise: Key Status "Unprotected"

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, react-google-recaptcha

Does anyone know why the "Key Status" in Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise says, "Unprotected" and how to fix it please? Thank you!

Double checked all keys are in place.

I have Googled extensively. I found a post on Google Help where someone reported the same problem, but I didn't see a resolution. Any ideas?

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez32Q.jpg)